# Pivoting Table Working Mechanism

Tags: reactjs, pivot, pivot-table

I have been studying about pivot tables recently, in Excel and other spreadsheets. I am thinking of building such a tool in the web platform in ReactJS. I surfed for a while and came across http://orbjs.net/, however it is no longer being maintained.This library is good, however I do not understand how exactly the data is being manipulated. 
Can someone provide me some link, as to learn the actual logic or algorithm for this data manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [pivottable.js](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable), this is popular open-source jQuery plugin. I'm not sure that ReactJS is a right tool for writing widgets like that; good old vanilla JS with direct DOM manipulation might be better choice from performance/resources usage.

Note that all javascript-only pivot table widgets that process data on the client side can process only rather small datasets; in real-life usage scenarios server side part is unavoidable (OLAP server or backend that will perform pivot data calculation on the server-side).